# How to capture android back key/button press on a web app (only JavaScript, HTML5/CSS, no Java)?

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, web-applications

The following code works okay, when you open in android/android-chrome browser.

window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "Confirm your actions before exiting."; }

But, when you save the app to the android home-screen as a web app, and then app runs in full screen mode, this has no effect.

Is there any alternative for WebApp mode? 
Any way to capture the back button press via HTML5 or Javascript APIs ?

Comment: If you read on the title, no Java. This is for WebApp. You can not get device APIs in javascript, can you?

Comment: No, this is for pure HTML/Javascript. You can not do Android Programming. The links you provided above are for WebView Android Native API. You can not use android API's in HTML page. The Web app I am referring to is just a html page which displays in full screen mode by default.

Comment: I am having this same issue (onbeforeunload doesn't work once you've installed to homescreen).  The best I've been able to do so far is use onpopstate with a guard state that I push on app launch.  But that has a problem where you end up having to press the back button twice to leave the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using cordova/phonegap

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackKeyDown, false);
```